# Implement a custom error controller in Symfony 4.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-4.4

What i have done:

I have created this custom controller cause I want to pass to the error pages some extra variables.

```
#Controller/CustomErrorControler.php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\Base\BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;

class CustomErrorController extends BaseController
{

    public function show(FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        return $this->getView('bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error.html.twig', [
            "code" => $exception->getStatusCode(),
            "message" =>$exception->getStatusText()
        ]);
    }
}
```

and the enabled

```
#config/packages/framework.yaml
error_controller: App\Controller\CustomErrorController::show
```

I have followed the documentation directly. My problem is that I need, for non-production stages to get the default exception templates provided by the framework.

I have tried to extend `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ErrorController` but I'm getting errors for autowiring.

Maybe I should use `Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\ErrorRenderer\ErrorRendererInterface`
Any ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it by using different `framework.yaml` for Prod

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your custom controller only in production you can modify your `config/packages/framework.yaml` file by adding the `when` clause, like this:

```
when@prod:
    framework:
        error_controller: App\Controller\CustomErrorController::show
```

This will ensure that your custom error controller is only used in the production environment, while the default exception templates are used in other environments